# Javascript array to html div tag .aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, arrays

I have an array in JS that I get from c# back end as...

```
<script>        
        var categoryLists = <%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.categoryList) %>;
</script>
```

And my HTML is

```
<div id="categories">
</div>
```

What is the best way that I can display the contents of the JS array in the div with id as categories?

PS- I am open to both JS, and Jquery. I also have a huge c# backend.

Comment: @akerr has the best answer - what have you tried thus far?

Comment: The "best" way (from the pre-edit) would probably be to generate the HTML in the .aspx file rather than after the page has loaded, so you don't get the FOUC (flash of unstyled content).

Comment: @freedomn-m... I am putting my html code in the .aspx file and noth .aspx.cs file.

Comment: @RockiesMaginNumber, yes akerr did have the best idea indeed.. I was trying to do a for loop but that didn't turn out to be efficient. I tried a jquery function and that was not working. But no worries coz problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what the data looks like, I would suggest something like this.

**EDIT:** Another option that may be a bit cleaner:

JS

```
let list = document.getElementById('category-list')
categoryLists.forEach(function (category) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  list.appendChild(li);
  li.innerHTML += category;
});
```

---

JS

```
let list = document.getElementById('category-list')
for (var category in categoryLists) {
  list.innerHTML += '<li>' + category + '</li>';
  console.log(category);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="categories">
<ul id="category-list">
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still sort of new to ES6, and I've read a bit about "let" vs "var" - is there any reason you define the "list" and "li" variables using "let" and then the for loop with a "var"? I'm sure it was just quick typing and also sure it'll work fine either way. Just curious about the semantics.

Comment: let vs var: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. The data is an array. Sorry, I was not able to reply earlier. :D

Answer (score 2):

While essentially the same as @akerr's existing js answer, assuming that categoryList outputs as an array, here's a one-liner that will generate the same result.

```js
var categories = ["category 1", "category 2", "category 3"];

$("#categories").append("<ul>" + categories.map((e, i) => "<li>" + e + "</li>").join("") + "</ul>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="categories">
</div>
```

Comment: This is really clean code. But I am going with the longer version to make it really readable. Thank you :D